# Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-handler, jobintentservice

Initializing a Handler inside JobIntentService when offline invokes this issue

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
       at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
       at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
       at JobIntentSericeClass.calculateExtras(DataManager.java:288)
       at JobIntentSericeClass.onHandleBlockingIntent(DataManager.java:499)
       at JobIntentSericeClass.onHandleWork(DataManager.java:100)
       at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:391)
       at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:382)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please refer the following code:

```
public class JobIntentServiceClass extends JobIntentService {

@Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
       onHandleBlockingIntent(intent);
    }

private void onHandleBlockingIntent(Intent intent) {
    calculateExtras();
}

private void calculateExtras() {
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // some async task here
                }
            }
        }, 5000);
}
}
```

I got an error on the line where handler is initialized. And also it happens when the app is offline. Online scenario works fine. Seems really strange

Comment: Please post your code also

Comment: @CaoMinhVu done

Comment: Try this instead:

final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: Thanks @CaoMinhVu that solved my problem